# Datastax OpsCenter Install Cluster Error: 400 Client Error when retrieving package_information

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm attempting to use OpsCenter 6.1 to install a new cluster. OpsCenter successfully ssh's to each of the nodes in the cluster then appears to nearly immediately error out on each node with the following message:

```
400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://<opscenter>:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/<node-id>/package_information
```

When attempting to reach that page myself I receive a 404 error with this message:

```
{"brief": "error", "message": "{\"type\":\"ApiException\",\"code\":404,\"msg\":\"Can't find object for given parameters: {:job-id nil, :node-id \\\"<node-id>\\\"}\"}", "type": "NoSuchResource"}
```

Note that <opscenter> (above) is the IP address of my local install, and <node-id> is the ID of the node.

Considering that I don't receive the 400 error myself I'm assuming that I'm unable to replicate the scenario that occurs during the install because of some perviously executed steps that are rolled back.

Any insight into what might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some more information - I'm able to manually navigate to http://172.23.1.1:8888/api/v1/lcm/nodes/8b7fd5dd-0045-44fb-b019-20c5565f297a and obtain information about the node, however http://172.23.1.1:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/8b7fd5dd-0045-44fb-b019-20c5565f297a/package_information doesn't provide anything. The 'internal' resource isn't defined within the OpsCenter API documentation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

LCM developer here... It's hard to know exactly what's wrong based on the information provided. But here are some tips:

1. If there's an api error during a job, the error will be recorded in opscenterd.log (usually in /var/log/opscenter in package installs, or in something like ./log/ in tarball installs).
2. The internal api is private and is not publicly documented. It's authenticated via a per-node secret token that's only valid during the lifetime of a job, so it's fairly challenging to try to ping internal urls manually, we've never needed to have someone try to ping internal api's to successfully diagnose issues in the past. It's not something I'd recommend spending a lot of time on.
3. You might get more context about LCM is doing when the error happens by turning the "lcm" logger up to debug in opscenter's logback.xml and restarting opscenterd.

Comment: Added the DEBUG option and looking at /var/logs/opscenter/opscenterd.log. It looks as though the failure occurs after both nodes report a milestone to opscenter with the message "Uploaded facts to OpsCenter server". Next I receive job-event of subtype "package-proxy" with message "Not using proxy". Next a message "Sending WILL_FAIL to job status channel for job ...". Finally, I receive the error messages from both nodes: "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://172.23.100.37:8888/api/v1/lcm/internal/nodes/8b7fd5dd-0045-44fb-b019-20c5565f297a/package_information". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't something more clear prior to WILL_FAIL (or as part of the WILL_FAIL message). My spidey sense tells me there is something weird with your network. Sending facts may be the first time that the target-node attempts to "phone-home" to the LCM server. Are you sure there isn't a firewall or proxy blocking access from your target nodes to 172.23.100.27:8888? Like can you 'curl http://172.23.100:8888/api/v1/lcm/' from a target node? If not, that's your problem and you need to sort out your network issues in order to allow that communication.

Comment: If that doesn't do it, It's likely I won't be able to help you in this forum. If you have access to DataStax support, reach out to them and they can escalate you to me to troubleshoot together on a call if they can' sort you out. If you're in the startup program or something, ping whoever your sales/whatever contact is and tell them you need help... Even if you don't officially have support we'll try to get you sorted.

Comment: I attempted what you mention and found that curl works just fine for hitting that other API. Also, considering that we get a 400 response from the server, it implies that the communications between the node and OpsCenter is functional (OpsCenter is returning a 400 response). The big question: why isn't that resource available?? I've reached out to our sales reps in hopes that they'll provide input. Fingers crossed, and thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I also idle in pound-opscenter DataStax academy slack: https://academy.datastax.com/slack